# Tax deduction for legal fee in defending my current job related to a threatening letter?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, california, employment-law

I paid around 750 dollars last year to consult lawyers regarding a threatening letter from a former employer related to company confidential information where they asked me to sign additional confidentiality agreements and threatened a bit. There was no lawsuit. The lawyer gave me advice and that was pretty much the end of it.

Form 529 says this and it's a legal expense that was incurred trying to defend against a former employer.

> You can deduct legal expenses that are related to doing or keeping
>   your job, such as those you paid to defend yourself against criminal
>   charges arising out of your trade or business.

Based on that it seems it could be an 'above the line' subtraction from the gross income,
The form also says:

> On the dotted line next to line 36, enter the amount of your
>   deduction and identify it as indicated.
>
> Attorney fees and court costs for actions involving certain unlawful 
>   dis-crimination claims, but only to the ex-tent of gross
>   income from such actions (see Pub. 525). Identify as “UDC.”

- Can these fees be deducted in federal and states like CA, as above-the-line deductions?
- If so, where in forms to deduct them? Should it go into adjustments to income line 36 of schedule 1 of 2018 1040?

Comment: You say 'former employer' - were you employed by them at the time of the letter and legal expenses, or were they already your former employer by that point?

Comment: @yoozer8 they already were former employer when i received the letter. i was employed at another place by then.

Comment: @yoozer8 in the letter they threatened to notify my current employer about confidentiality issue. i contacted a lawyer bc i didn't want them to contact my current employer. i think IRS allows tax deduction to save my job and the implication of threat was that it could have impacted my job status.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it seems that you can deduct legal expenses that are related to your employment. It should be entered on Line 21 of your return. There are more answers on ttlc.intuit.com/community/tax-credits-deductions/discussion/are-employment-related-legal-fees-still-deductible-in-california/00/174203